# Why is the hard disk drive too hot?

Tags: 11.04, hardware, temperature

The Hard disk drive got too hot after a while of running Ubuntu. I've checked the system monitor and there weren't any thing strange.

I have Packard Bell EasyNote TJ75 with ATI card 512MB core i5.

Comment: It could just be the way your computer is designed. Have you tried with another operating system?

Comment: You need to know the actual temperature of the hard drive and its thermal specification. Use [lm-sensors](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SensorInstallHowto) for the former, and the hard drive manufacturer's documentation for the latter. `sudo lshw -class disk` should tell you what kind of hard drive you have.

Comment: Indeed, what is "too hot" and how do you know?

Comment: @Ethan Turkeltaub  it's normal in windows 7 
@psusi i can't touch it

Comment: That doesn't really clarify things.  Check the temperature in the disk utility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are u facing the issue on laptop or desktop?

I faced this issue and after much struggle, I am able to resolve the issue. I was not able to use my laptop as my HDD was getting too hot.

Do the following and come back with the result.

1. install powertop
2. run it in sudo and go to the last tab in that application.
3. Check if you are seeing some thing like "SATA Link..." as bad power setting.

If you see as above reply to this mail. I will provide the solution.

Good you have the same problem. Try these

1. Follow the link to install TLP [TLP](https://github.com/linrunner/TLP/wiki/TLP-Linux-Advanced-Power-Management)
2. Once installed open the file /etc/default/tlp
3. Search for SATA in that file.

make the changes as follow:

`#SATA aggressive link power management (ALPM):`

`#min_power/medium_power/max_performance`

`SATA_LINKPWR_ON_AC=min_power`

`SATA_LINKPWR_ON_BAT=min_power`

1. If you still want more optimization follow these
   a. Add noatime,nodiratime to your root mount disk property in /etc/fstab

Here is my example:

UUID=2961c207-9781-425e-9e6e-18641b21e52c /               ext4    errors=remount-ro,noatime,nodiratime  0       1

Reboot the machine for all changes to take effect.

Do this you HDD will cool down. :)

Comment: yes i see this line : SATA link power management as bad power setting ad you say

Comment: See my updated comment.

Comment: SATA link power, is literally that, power management for the link between the hard drive and the motherboard. At the most, this can knock off 1 or 2 W of power. Not much.

Answer (score -1):

It may be that the hard drive is dying, I worked in a computer repair store and the general point of no return is when you touch the drive and practically burn yourself, I would reccomend getting a new hard drive ASAP, @Ethan Turkeltaub, It is very rare for a hard drive to overheat enough to be noticed just because of the way the computer is designed, if such were the case, then the drive would die within a year of being new, just from excessive heat!!

Comment: thank but the promlem was from the ATI Card Driver it's normal now

Comment: True, true.

Comment: Sorry to give you the -ve point but you are guiding the user to wrong direction. You are not considering all the possibility of issues. You are right that HDD start getting hot when they are about to die but in Linux there are many parameters which can cause the issue.