# Disk Utility changes bad sector counts

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility

I have been monitoring my HDD for a while now and noticed the following related to the amount of **Bad sectors** shown in the Disk app:

7 Months Ago - Brand new, sparky, Beam me up Scotty!
3 Months Ago - 3 Bad Sectors
2 Months ago - 17 Bad Sectors
1 Month Ago - 11 Bad Sectors
1 Week Ago - 9 Bad Sectors
3 Days Ago - 5 Bad Sectors
Today - 4 Bad Sectors

Did my HDD suddenly learn to heal?

Does my HDD include a hidden features (Small Elves that fix sectors instead of shoes)?

I know that bad sectors can increase because of usage, but decrease?. the only think I did was lower the temperature since I did what is mentioned here (It is the same HDD) [How to lower the HDD temperature](https://askubuntu.com/questions/251830/how-to-lower-the-hdd-temperature) so what influences in the decision to show what Bad sectors really are and how many actually are in the HDD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The count of bad sectors that the utility displays is the sum of the sectors that are:

1. Reallocated
2. Unrecoverable
3. Pending

When reading a sector fails, it is placed on the pending list.  The next time you try to write to the sector, the drive will try to write there, and if writing fails, it will reallocate the sector from the spare pool, if there are any spare sectors left.  If writing worked, then the count of bad sectors would go down.  This can happen because the sector was scrambled, but physically fine.  Often this will result from sudden loss of power in the middle of a write.