# Dell Latitude E5570 overheats on a single spot when running Ubuntu, not with Windows

Tags: dell, hardware, overheating, devices, lm-sensors

My Dell starts heating up on the marked spot (see photo below) immediately after booting any Linux distro I tried (Ubuntu 16.04, Ubuntu 14.04, Mint 18.2, Arch). This spot is cool on Windows. Also, the other site (bottom) is cold. I don't know what device is below neither why it happens. I checked with `sensors` (lm-sensors) and all is below 45°C, but obviously the part here has no sensor.

[image: Dell Latitude E5570 (128 SSD, intel i5, integrated graphics, 8 Gb RAM)]

There is no HDD in this laptop. Also, this spot is hot when runnig USB live.

I contacted Dell support and was informed that it is **palm rest assemby** that heats up. Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: It seems to be the HDD, see [the manual](http://topics-cdn.dell.com/pdf/latitude-e5570-laptop_owner's%20manual_en-us.pdf) page 12. [How to lower the HDD temperature](https://askubuntu.com/questions/251830/how-to-lower-the-hdd-temperature) might help you.

Comment: There is no HDD. Only SSD.

Comment: There is no palm rest "assembly" either. The palms rest on the enclosure, that's the palm rest, just plastic. What matter is what's inside right below that spot. I suggest you turn it upside down and check what's there. I suspect you'll find a removable cover and the SSD inside. SSDs do heat a lot sometimes.

Comment: Could you post the output of sensors anyway?

Comment: I have the same problem with an E5470. It gets hot on the same spot.
I have an nvme ssd in it. I've checked the temperatures but nothing unusual. On idle temp1/temp2 (mem/controller) is around 32/39°C. It's the same in Windows.
*But* in Windows the top of the case is cool. If I run an SSD benchmark then the temperatures go up a lot of course, but still the top of the case is not hot (the bottom is quite warn in this case tho).
There's some board under the hot place, top right here: https://youtu.be/fiHCDAQo1As?t=546

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Linux writes to the disk every time a read operation is carried out.

You could try disabling atime and diratime on the mounted disk to see if it helps.

Open /etc/fstab and find the mountpoint and add "noatime" and "nodiratime" to the row.

The row usually looks something like:

```
UUID=DriveIDStringHere /               ext4    errors=remount-ro,noatime,nodiratime 0      1
```

Disabling this might also prolong the longevity of your SSD.

Comment: But when booting USB live, this should not be a problem. Right?

Comment: @sawic Not necessarily. If the SSD has a swap partition the live session will use it.

Comment: “every time a read operation is carried out” Doesn't Ubuntu use `relatime` by default?

Answer (score 0):

Installing tlp solves this issue for Ubuntu and Arch distros